# updating android sdk downloading eclipse slow connection problems

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu

Just before leaving my apartment for Xmas, I was trying to download the library for Google maps api for Android 2.2. My sdk would.show the option to download it but it would.time out. So I tried deleting eclipse and downloading but then the download manager in ubuntu 11.10 would stop working. I then tried downloading eclipse this morning directly from a server at university of Oslo and it was downloading around 1 kb/3seconds which was at least progress. I guess my connection is really slow but I've dealt with slower, hopefully it will end after Christmas when people stop downloading junk, but how can I get the things I need? Is my sdk manager prioritizing which server is sending me information or is it coming from mountain view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the internet provider was 'choking' my line because the landlord forgot to pay the bill.

Answer (score 0):

Well first think if you really need to update Android SDK it does have a great of new features but if it's not something ASAP you might be able to live without it for a while.

Secondly if you really want the update with all you're heart you might want to just download by piece. Why don't you download separately ADT, Android SDK, and then each one of the versions.

Comment: Well I need access to Google maps library and the sdk keps timing out when I tried to download the package for 2.2. I will try doing it all separately when I get back to my computer. well see how it goes. thanks!